# Replace each item of explode

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have a string which basically consists of delimited json strings like (well dont ask me why. It's what I get)

```
{ foo: bar, baz: 1234 } || { foo: huh, baz: 9090 } || ..
```

So I explode these strings and decode them. Then I loop over them, generate a new object of them and pass it to an new array:

```
$toons = explode("||", $application->toons);
for($i=0;$i<count($toons);$i++) {
    $t[$i] = new WowApi(json_decode($toons[$i], true));
}
```

Well I really dislike this code. I would like to do this already in explode.

A python equivalent would be something like

```
toons = app_toons.split("||")
t = [api(toon) for toon in app_toons]
```

which is way more valuable in sense of readability - in my opinion

So my question is: Is there a more elegant way to create my array?

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure `"||"` sequence will never occur inside of json parts? If no - don't explode string naively.
2. `for(;;)` loop can be replaced by `foreach` loop. But if you want to go deeper you can use `array_walk` function. PHP doc has good examples.